# c++ 3D game engine

Tags: c++, 3d, directx

I would like to understand/conceive a 3D game engine. Which books/references/tutorials would you recommend? I would like them to be about C++/DirectX and not Java.

Comment: Minecraft is a great game written in Java... Okay, Notch sucked at programming it, the game is still great though.

Comment: @JustSid This isn’t the first time I’ve heard Notch’s programming skills criticised. Do you have any sources for that? I’m mildly interested by the fact that this seems to be a recurring sentiment (I’ve never played Minecraft so I can’t tell either way).

Comment: there was a game of total 96kb(.exe) and running just like quake 2 - 3. What was it made in ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [An easy to use 3D graphics engine for a simple game?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6630902/an-easy-to-use-3d-graphics-engine-for-a-simple-game)

Comment: @KonradRudolph Well, I have obviously never seen Notch's code, but I know how buggy Minecraft is and how really not well tested it was, especially in the time before Jeb became part of Mojang. So I'm afraid the only source I can give you are the old Minecraft versions...

Comment: Kkrieger was the name of 3D 96KB game. The smallest code for a shooter game

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As one of the developers, I would recommend looking at the open-source [Linderdaum Engine](http://www.linderdaum.com). It works on Windows, Android and MacOS and is using OpenGL 3 and OpenGL ES 2.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at [Ogre3D](http://www.ogre3d.org/). It's a free opensource 3d engine that works on many platforms. You can read it's documentation and examine it's code

Comment: While Ogre3D is probably great (“probably” since I’ve never used it), it’s also not really a good reference code for beginners, it doesn’t necessarily follow standards of modern C++ programming, and finally it explicitly states in its FAQ that it’s *not* a game engine.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I think you can still learn many concepts from it. Such as scene graph, renderer and so on

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at: [Game Engine Architecture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1568814135) ISBN-13: 978-1568814131

Comment: This is a good reading for beginners. However, it lacks details in many advanced topics like animations blending pipelines and complex material systems.

Answer (score 0):

[Now read this](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/95842-how-to-make-a-3d-game-engine/page__gopid__1923995&#entry1923995) as it explains it very well but you might need to get a better physics and graphics library for 3d but other than that it is great.